# Heap size increasing rapidly spring boot application

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot, jvm

I have application on spring boot, using mongoDB and hibernate for MySQL.
Heap size of application continuously increasing in production. I have provided maximum heap size as 24 GB, which is already huge. Now heap used is reaching 23 GB. 
Is it good to take heap dump of such huge memory, will it effect performance as it is live application.

Another way to detect memory leak in same?
Or other way to analyse hibernate or mongo metrics?

Comment: Yes, taking a heap dump will "freeze the world" and will essentially cause a production outage, would not recommend. If you are using Spring Boot, did you include the actuator in your build? It won't give you heap metrics but will give you other useful stuff. The memory leak is unlikely to be in hibernate or mongo, more likely the way you have implemented caching or something like that. Does the heap gradually grow in dev/qa/uat as well? Take a heap dump there and analyse that for ideas?

Comment: Another suggestion, are you running with jmx enabled? You could try connecting to it with jconsole and see if any useful mbeans are exposed

Comment: I do have jmx enabled, but unable to find any useful out there, can you give an example what should I look for in this as it's shows 3 options: "Attributes", "Operations", "Notifications".

Comment: @Matt Unable to produce on stg/dev due to no traffic. And application mostly consists of JMS listeners and spring Schedulers.

Comment: Are you reading from the JMS listeners into an internal unbounded queue, doing some processing on that queue, and writing to hibernate/mongo? That could cause a memory leak if there's no back pressure on the JMS consumer (you won't be able to write to database as fast as you consume from JMS). Are you able to knock up a quick app that generates simulated traffic on stg/dev? Personally, that would be my next step. You want to be able to reproduce this issue on dev rather than debugging in production

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the heap memory in jprofiler or jvisualvm. One of the options could be that heap would take all the memory you provide, but use only some part of it. In general it would depend of Garbage Collector algorithm. I would recommend you to perform following steps:

1) Check if the memory taken by heap is actually used (you can see it in jprofiler or jvisualvm). If the application is taking all memory but doesn't use it you can restrict it with some reasonable value using Xmx jvm argument.

2) See the memory usage under the load and idle. See the difference. Depending on the operations you do there might be some objects sitting in memory, but they should be collected time-to time.

3) If it is really leak and you see the memory reserved by jvm is really used and never released - take a memory dump and see what kind of objects are sitting there (again try jprofiler or jvisualvm). This will give you a clue where to look.

Comment: That is an excellent point - the JVM will eventually fill all the heap you give it, but isn't necessarily using all of it, and isn't necessarily in danger of falling over

Comment: How can I see memory usage under the load and idle?

Comment: @Ionwolf it depends on what your application does, i.e. if it is a web services you can generate some load like 30 threads doing 100 calls(using jmeter for example) of certain service and see the picture. If it is live you would probably have some time during day or night when the system is not used much. Otherwise you'll have to experiment in staging or even local environment.

Comment: It's seems to be issue relates Query plan cache of hibernate, as I took heap dump for staging and it contains char[] with sql queries. Any suggestions to limit this cache or disable same?